# elegant way to check file directory path valid in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read content of all files under a specific directory. I find it is a bit tricky if path name is not ends with `/`, then my code below will not work (will have I/O exception since `pathName+f` is not valid -- missing `/` in the middle). Here is a code example to show when it works and when it not works,

I can actually check if pathName ends with `/` by using endsWith, just wondering if more elegant solutions when concatenate path and file name for a full name?

My requirement is, I want to give input pathName more flexible to ends with both `\` and not ends with `\`.

Using Python 2.7.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

#pathName = '/Users/foo/Downloads/test/' # working
pathName = '/Users/foo/Downloads/test' # not working, since not ends with/
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(pathName) if isfile(join(pathName, f))]
for f in onlyfiles:
    with open(pathName+f, 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
        print content
```

Comment: Why do you use both `os.path.join(pathName, f)` and `pathName + f`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just use join again:

```
pathName = '/Users/foo/Downloads/test' # not working, since not ends with/
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(pathName) if isfile(join(pathName, f))]
for f in onlyfiles:
    with open(join(pathName, f), 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
        print content
```

Or you could  use *glob* and forget join:

```
from glob import glob

pathName = '/Users/foo/Downloads/test' # not working, since not ends with/

onlyfiles = (f for f in glob(join(pathName,"*")) if isfile(f))

for f in onlyfiles:
   with open(f, 'r') as content_file:
```

or combine it with filter for a more succinct solution:

```
onlyfiles = filter(isfile, glob(join(pathName,"*")))
```

Comment: It works, thanks Padraic! Vote up and mark as answer.